# Edit the style/template of a control created from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, themes, resourcedictionary

I'm styling WPF's Calendar control and I've reached a point in XAML where there's a grid with no elements in it, just divided by rows and columns where the day numbers are.

I've snooped and decompiled (`void PopulateGrids()`) and have learned that in code-behind the Calendar is creating `CalendarDayButton` and feeding it to the grid.

I need to change the style/theme in-order to change the colors (of those `CalendarDayButton`) and I'm not sure how to do that.
I've tried applying a style to all `CalendarDayButton` in said grid, but that didn't work.

Any suggestions?
*P.S. I'd rather stay away from code-behind because what I'm working on is a style in a resource-dictionary and not a user-control.*

Comment: Check out this link which shows extensive styling with Calendar http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Microsoft page for [Calendar Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468218%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), copy the style code into your resources block and make changes as needed. If you need to create additional properties for settings etc then you can do so with an attached property, that way you don't need to create a new calandar control. If you're having difficulty figuring out which parts of the template correspond to things you're seeing on-screen then put a breakpoint in your code somewhere, add the calandar control variable name to your watch window and click on the little magnifying glass to bring up the WPF visualizer...that will let you traverse the visual tree and visually see which part of the control each section is rendering.